# What is the prefix number, in bytes, of a native segwit address?

Tags: segregated-witness, bech32-address, base58, bip350-bech32m

I've seen lots of tables on which bytes to use as the prefix for types of addresses. For example 0x00 for legacy addresses starting with a 1. But what's the prefix for native segwit 'bc1q'? I've tried using the base58 table with no success.
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Native segwit addresses are not encoded using base58, but using a different encoding system called bech32. The details can be found in [BIP 173](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki). For the  segwit v1+ addresses that will be used for Taproot, see the amended bech32m encoding in [BIP 350](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0350.mediawiki).

In short, the addresses consist of:

- A *human readable part*, which is `bc` for Bitcoin mainnet segwit addresses.
- A separator (`1`)
- A payload (storing the actual script data), consisting of:

  - A character for the witness version (`q` for witness v0, `p` for witness v1, ...). See the BIPs for details on the character set.
  - A variable number of characters storing the witness program (32 characters for 20-byte witness programs like P2WPKH has; 52 characters for 32-byte witness programs like P2WSH or P2TR have). The 8-bit data is converted to 5-bit groups, and encoded using the bech32 character set.
- 6 characters checksum, using the checksum algorithm specified in BIP173 or BIP350.